# Is there a way to make a sequence with custom behavior or similar functions?

Tags: postgresql, function, generator, sequence

I want to make a sequence that gives me random values. Two sequential calls should give similar values, that differ just a little bit (with a maximal STEP). Means I want to make a sequence of values that changes smooth and in a random direction.

I did a simple function that does what I want. But the Problem is - it cant store previous values.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION smooth_random_integer(VAL INTEGER, STEP INTEGER, MIN INTEGER, MAX INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER
    AS
    $rand_smooth_integer$
    BEGIN
        VAL := VAL + floor(random() * (STEP * 2 + 1) - STEP);
        IF VAL > MAX THEN
            RETURN MAX;
        ELSIF VAL < MIN THEN
            RETURN MIN;
        END IF;
        RETURN VAL;
    END;
    $rand_smooth_integer$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

That means the insert below produces very similar values, always very near to the INITIAL variable.

```
INSERT INTO datapoint_values (ts, int_value)
    (SELECT ts, smooth_random_integer(INITIAL, STEP, MIN, MAX)
    FROM generate_series(TIMESTAMP_START, TIMESTAMP_END, TS_STEP) as ts);
```

How can I rewrite my code to achieve desired output?

I had an idea to use sequences.

Problem with postgresql sequences is that they 1) have a stable defined step and 2) are always incremental or always decremental.

Is there a way to do what I want? Other tool besides sequences are welcome too.

Edit 1:

MIN, MAX, STEP and INITIAL are defined at the start of the script. They are INTEGERs. For example 0, 100, 2, 40.

generate_series(...) gives a table that produces Timestamps from TIMESTAMP_START to TIMESTAMP_END with a defined step TS_STEP.